# temporaries not behaving as const

Tags: c++, constants, temporaries

Its unclear to me whether a temporary assumes type of const or not, in an expression as shown below.

```
#include <iostream>

class X {
public:
X(int a) { i = a; cout << "X(int) [" << (int)this << "]" << endl; }

X& operator+(const X& x) 
{ 
i += x.i; 
cout << "X operator+(const X&) [" << (int)this << "]" << endl; 
return *this; 
}

~X() { cout << "~X [" << (int)this << "]" << endl; }

private:
int i;
};


int main() 
{
X x = X(3) + X(4);
cout << "done" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

`X(3)` behaves like non-const (because I can call `operator+`, while `X(4)` behaves like const(because, it needs const argument in `operator+`).

Can someone clarify, what is the right understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to class types, when you create a temporary of const type, that temporary will be const. And when you create a temporary of non-const type, that temporary will be non-const. That's it. I.e. as far as the exact type is concerned, there no connection between const and temporaries at all. Temporary of class type never assumes const by itself. It is you who can explicitly impose const on it.

In your example nether `X(3)` nor `X(4)` is const. Since `X(3)` is not const, you can call a non-const method on it.

It is not correct to say that your `X(4)` "behaves as const". There's no indication that it "behaves as const" in your example whatsoever. Just because you were able to initialize a const reference with something does no mean that that something is const.

In your question you state that you "need const argument in `operator+`". That's incorrect. You don't need const *argument* in your `operator+`. Your *parameter* `x` is declared as const reference. A const reference can be easily bound to const arguments as well as to non-const arguments. In your case const reference parameter `x` is bound to a non-const temporary argument `X(4)`.

Comment: But as i mentioned, operator+ requires a *const* X& argument for this to compile. If i just have X& operator+(X& x), the compilation fails.

Comment: @Chethan: That's caused by the properties of references, not by properties of temporaries. In C++ only const references can be bound to temporaries. Non-const references cannot be bound to temporaries. Whether the temporary itself is const or not does not matter at all.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: That's really about references, not about temporaries.

Answer (score 2):

You can call non-`const` members of temporaries.  But you cannot bind a non-`const` reference to a temporary.

Comment: Just a nit, but that should be "you cannot initialize a non-const reference with an rvalue expression".  It's very possible to obtain non-const references bound to a temporary.  (Try `std::ostream& s = std::ostringstream().flush();` for example.)

Answer (score 2):

Historically, temporaries are rvalues, and rvalues aren't (and can't be)
cv-qualified.  This rule worked well for non-class types, or for class
types with no member functions; since const-ness intervenes in function
overload resolution, the cv-qualification of a temporary must be
maintained.  If a function returns simply `X`, then the temporary is
*not* const, and you can call non-const functions on it; if the
functions returns `X const`, then the temporary is const, and you can't
call non-const functions on it.  As a general rule, it's probably
preferable to return class types as `const`; i.e. `X const f()`, rather 
than `X f()`.  But there are definitely exceptions, and no body does it,
even in the cases where it would be more appropriate.  And finally, 
there are contexts where you can't specify the const-ness—function
style type conversions, for example—where the syntax doesn't
provide a means of specifying cv-qualifiers (except by using typedef's).

You might want to look at the output from the following code:

```
class C
{
    std::string myComment;
public:
    C( std::string const& comment ) : myComment( comment ) {}

    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "Non const " << myComment << std::endl;
    }

    void f() const
    {
        std::cout << "Const " << myComment << std::endl;
    }
};

typedef C const CC;

C
c()
{
    return C("function return value");
}

C const
cc()
{
    return C("function return value");
}

int
main()
{
    C("function style conversion").f();
    CC("function style conversion").f();
    c().f();
    cc().f();
}
```

Comment: I think the advice to return class-types as const is positively obsolete now. In C++11 this interferes heavily with move semantics, which only work for non-const rvalues.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't know.  I suspect that it depends on the application; returning const will certainly cause some errors to be caught by the compiler, which can be a strong argument.  On the other hand, almost nobody does it, so the errors it would catch can't be that frequent.  As for move semantics: how many classes actually support them?  I'm not sure that they're that important.  (But again, it depends on the application.)

Comment: Hm... `string`. `vector`. Any standard library container. Iostreams? Unique pointers. Locks. Hmm...

Answer (score 1):

In the following code:

```
X x = X(3) + X(4);
```

`X(3)` creates a temporary non-const object which invokes `operator+`, passing `X(4)` which is another temporary non-const object as const reference argument to the function.

A non-const object can be passed to a function as const object (passing by reference), but a const object cannot be passed by non-const reference to a function. That is the difference.